# Medicine as a tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[medicine](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medicine) has 7 questions and doesn't really add anything to the categorisation of any of them.  More specific tags could easily be applied to all of them, therefore I'm inclined to burninate it.  *Can anyone think of a reason why it should stay*?

Comment: Are you Trogdor? ;) I think the tag should go. As it stands, we do not take questions of a medical nature (if for solicitation of medical advice), and therefore they should all fall under some other branch of physiology or biology.

Comment: Agree that anything appropriate for "Medicine" would qualify for a more specific tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The medicine tag has been zapped!